# ErrorException Undefined variable $teambatter (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp - 1.0.2\resources\views\products\indexpublic.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

[image: see this image]

Here I have two folder named products and teamname. In team name, I have index.blade.php where I can view name like this [image: name image]
using this code

```
<td>{{ $teambatter->name }}</td>
```

Where TeambatterController.php have this code

```
public function index()
   {
       $teambatter = Teambatter::latest()->paginate(5);

       return view('teambatters.index',compact('teambatter'))
           ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
   }
```

The problem is when I view same name in indexpublic.blade.php in products folder using this code

```
<h1> {{ $teambatter->name }} </h1>
```

I got $teambater is undefine in indexpublic.blade.php.
How can I add this name to indexpublic.blade.php in the products folder?

its not working If I pass like this in my productConteroller.php

```
 public function indexpublic()
    {
        $teambatter = Teambatter::latest()->paginate(20);
         $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
         return view('products.indexpublic',compact('products'))
         ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);

    }
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, 'indexpublic']);
```

Comment: Do you have a controller for Products?  That's were you can pass the variable to the Products views.

Comment: How can I pass it there I update my ProductConroller.php see my post thanks`

Comment: You're only passing $products to the indexpublic view.  You also need to pass the $teambatter variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the indexpublic() function you're passing the $products variable to the view, but not the $teambatter variable.

This should work:

```
public function indexpublic()
{
  $teambatter = Teambatter::latest()->paginate(20);
  $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
  return view('products.indexpublic',compact('products', 'teambatter'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Error gone but a new error is appire which is Exception
Property [name] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp - 1.0.2\resources\views\products\indexpublic.blade.php)

Comment: I would add {{ dump($teambatter) }} to the view, to check what data is being passed to the view.